# Autofill all the number fields on a click of a button

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I am working on a functionality on a button which auto fills all the input fields in my form.
The challenge here is that, the form contains dynamic number of input fields and also the id of the input fields is pretty complex to determine. So, is there a way to target all the input `type = "number"` only and fill them with a fixed number of value(Lets say 8).

**Here is my form code :**

```
<form id="form_id" action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="number" id="sdf" name="somename1">
  <input type="number" id="asd" name="somename2">
  <input type="number" id="fas" name="somename3">
  <input type="number" id="fea" name="somename4">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#form_id input[type=number]').forEach(input => input.value = 8);`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. How can I use this if it is for a drop down  input?

Comment: Change the selector accordingly, like `#form_id select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily in jquery

```
$("form").each(function(){
$(this).find(':input[type="number"]').val(8)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery when your document is ready, get all these inputs with

```
$(':input[type="number"]')
```

and then set the value